# PHPMailer: Mass Emails - Send all variable messages at once, instead of individually

Tags: php, email, loops, variables, phpmailer

i'm currently trying to figure out the best way to do this.

The current system i've made sends email one by one and fills in the information for each entry as in the array, such as email, first name and last name.

The problem here is if i send alot of messages it takes forever to run through as it's calling a function everytime, instead i want it to send them all at once through one single function.

I know you can add multiple to's but then the body of the email won't send the correct information relative to each email. If anyone can help me with this i'd really appreciate it, as i've searched all over for a solution.

```
<?php
require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';?>

<?php
/* Block List */
$blocklist = array('emailblocked@gmail.com', 'emailblocked2@gmail.com');

$emaillist = array(

    array(
        'Email'=>'example@gmail.com', 
        'First Name'=>'John',
        'Last Name'=>'Doe'
    ), 

    array(
        'Email'=>'example2@gmail.com', 
        'First Name'=>'Joe',
        'Last Name'=>'Doe'
    ), 

    array(
        'Email'=>'example3@gmail.com', 
        'First Name'=>'Jane',
        'Last Name'=>'Doe'
    ),
);



foreach($emaillist as $emailkey){

    if (in_array($emailkey['Email'], $blocklist)) {

        echo 'Message has been been blocked for '.$emailkey['Email'].'<br>';

    }else{

        $mail = new PHPMailer;

        // $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'username@example.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'passwordgoeshere';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->From = 'noreply@example.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'Example';

        $mail->addAddress($emailkey['Email'], $emailkey['First Name'].' '.$emailkey['Last Name']);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');

        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = $emailkey['First Name'].' '.$emailkey['Last Name'];

        $emailtemp = file_get_contents('templates/temp-1.html');
        $emailtempfilteremail = str_replace("[[email]]", $emailkey['Email'], $emailtemp);
        $emailtempfilterfirstname = str_replace("[[firstname]]", $emailkey['First Name'], $emailtempfilteremail);
        $emailtempfilterlastname = str_replace("[[lastname]]", $emailkey['Last Name'], $emailtempfilterfirstname);
        $mail->Body = $emailtempfilterlastname;

        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a spicy email!';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent.';
            echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            echo 'Message has been sent to '.$emailkey['Email'].'<br>';
        }

        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

    }   

}

?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Sending mass emails with a PHPMailer script is likely to get your server blocked for spam. There are plenty of free and easy to use newsletter type services. Remember also that if you are going to be sending mass emails you need to offer to recipients the ability to opt-out, and have a system in-place to deal with that.

Comment: There's [an example of how to do exactly this](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) in the examples bundled with PHPMailer. There's nothing inherently likely to get you blacklisted by using PHPMailer for sending large volumes, but you do need to tread carefully.

Comment: @Synchro i'm using Mandrill so it will take care of being blocked as it's made for Mass Email Marketting.

PHP Mailers example doesn't do what i need it to do. I want it to send say 50 all at once, rather than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc . I know this can be done by adding numerous to's but as a trade off it then wont send the custom body.

Comment: There's no magic to Mandrill - if you send spam through it you'll get blocked just as much as if you send it yourself. If you want to send 50 simultaneously from PHP, fire up multiple processes with the `pcntl` extension, but it won't actually help you very much as you'll be increasing overhead enormously. You can set `SMTPKeepAlive = true` in PHPMailer which will reduce overhead a lot, but it still won't send simultaneous messages - nothing will. There isn't an option in SMTP to send multiple messages with different bodies simultaneously, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hey @Synchro, there wont be spam sent through it, it's for a legitimate email marketing campaign, based of subscriber lists we own the rights to. Thank you for the tip on the SMTPKeepAlive = true i'll try that and see if it helps. Also i wasn't aware about not being able to send simultaneously, is there a way to ensure the server will finish through the array without having to leave the page open?

Comment: I'm not saying you are sending spam, just what would happen if you did! Don't send it as part of a page action; use a cron script or background process to do your actual sending and just set it up through your web pages. If you want to send much faster, install a local mail server like postfix and use that to relay - it will be far faster and more reliable than sending directly. Another tip if you are waiting for a page load - call [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) early on so that it won't stop if your browser closes the connection.

Comment: Thank you @Synchro, looks like the ignore_user_abort() and SMTPKeepAlive did the trick for speed and for fall back, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an example of [how to send to a list from a database efficiently](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) in the examples bundled with PHPMailer. There's nothing inherently likely to get you blacklisted by using PHPMailer for sending large volumes, but you do need to tread carefully. Mandrill isn't magic - it's as vulnerable as anything else to being blocked if you send spam through it.

If you want to send 50 simultaneously from PHP, fire up multiple processes with the `pcntl` extension, but it won't actually help you very much as you'll be increasing overhead enormously. You can set `SMTPKeepAlive = true` in PHPMailer which will reduce overhead a lot (it avoids making a new connection for every message), but it still won't send simultaneous messages - nothing will. There isn't an option in SMTP to send multiple messages with different bodies simultaneously on the same connection.

Sending to a big list during a page load in a browser is very unreliable; use a cron script or background process to do your actual sending and just set it up through your web interface. One tip if you are waiting for a page load - call [`ignore_user_abort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) early on so that it won't stop sending if your browser closes the connection - and beware the page refresh! If you want to send much faster, install a local mail server like postfix and use that to relay - it will be far faster and more reliable than sending directly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible with a modification of your code, the problem is not with the `PHPMailer` itself, but with your approach. You should avoid using an new instance of the class inside a `loop` (this leads to memory exhaustion with large lists), instead, only invoke `$mail->addAddress(...)` or `$mail->Subject(...)` inside the `foreach` loop.
If you read the source code of the `PHPMailer`, you will notice how exactly the functions `addAddress()`, `Subject()` or `Body()` works.

Your code should look something like this:

```
    <?php 

    /*Move your "generic" initialization outside the loop*/

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    // $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'username@example.com'; // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'passwordgoeshere'; // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587; // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->From = 'noreply@example.com';
    $mail->FromName = 'Bet Monkey';
    $mail->isHTML(true);  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $emailtemp = file_get_contents('templates/temp-1.html');
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a spicy email!';

   /*Start the loop by adding email addresses*/
  foreach($emaillist as $emailkey){
    if (in_array($emailkey['Email'], $blocklist)) {
    echo 'Message has been been blocked for '.$emailkey['Email'].'<br>';

    }else{
    $mail->addAddress($emailkey['Email'], $emailkey['First Name'].' '.$emailkey['Last Name']);     // Add a recipient
    $mail->Subject = $emailkey['First Name'].' '.$emailkey['Last Name'];

    $emailtempfilteremail = str_replace("[[email]]", $emailkey['Email'], $emailtemp);
    $emailtempfilterfirstname = str_replace("[[firstname]]", $emailkey['First Name'], $emailtempfilteremail);
    $emailtempfilterlastname = str_replace("[[lastname]]", $emailkey['Last Name'], $emailtempfilterfirstname);
    $mail->Body = $emailtempfilterlastname;



    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent to '.$emailkey['Email'].'<br>';
    }

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

  }  
}
```

Using the above approach I personally have send hundreds of thousands emails, but, as they say in the comments - you'll risking to be blacklisted (you can check [here](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) or [here](http://www.blacklistalert.org/) for details).

Comment: Hey @bodi0

I've just tried this and it made no improvement  to the speed or to the original code, it also didn't send them all at once, it continued to post one after another, if i close the window it'll stop and cut off

I want it to send say 50 all at once, rather than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc . I know this can be done by adding numerous to's but it then wont send the custom body.

Comment: Move `$mail->send() {...}` outside of the loop too.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i've tried this code too but it runs through one by one still it just doesn't show you through echos but i've just found out from Synchro that you can't send all at once, but SMTPKeepAlive will help keep the line open